# Azure OAuth2 and outrageous price: Do all users need to be in Active Directory at $6/month/user?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

We'd like to start using OAuth2 for SSO for a family of web apps. One solution is to use OAuth2 provided by Azure. It just looks *unreasonably* expensive, and I'm thinking there must be something I've missed.

As I understand it from [Microsoft identity platform (v2.0) overview - Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview), any users that need to login with Azure's OAuth2 solution need to be in Active Directory. We don't need the users to be able to do *anything* else but log in to our apps, but we do want them to be our accounts and not any other accounts they may have with Microsoft already.

Looking at the [AD price list](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/), we're talking $6 user/month, if we want "Company branding (customization of logon & logout pages, access panel)" and SLAs which we do.

So assuming we have say 100,000 users that is $600,000 pr month just for OAuth2 so they can log in? Even if we could go through a "Diamond-gold-platinum partner" or something and could get that at a 1/10 of the price, it is still outrageous.

Other alternatives we're considering are Auth0, Okta or hosting our own Keycloak instance(s), so there are (much) cheaper alternatives, but is this the cheapest way to use OAuth2 for app logins with Azure's hosted OAuth2?

And will this interfere with other identities they also have with Microsoft, e.g. any Office365 accounts that have nothing to do with our applications?

Comment: Are you looking for authentication for the users in your organization? Or from users from many different organization, or even not in any organization at all? If the latter, did you look at [Azure AD B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/external-identities/b2c/) while you were looking into this?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret: This is the answer I'm looking for. If you'd care to turn this comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for an enterprise identity service for your organization's users (and apps, devices, groups, etc.), then yes, [Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/active-directory/) Premium P1 will give you (with a whole bunch of additional capabilities and SLA) and currently costs somewhere around $6/user/month.

However, if you're simply looking for an identity provider for your app(s) which works for any user (not necessarily users and collaborators from one organization), then you may be looking for for a consumer identity and access management (CIAM) product. In the Microsoft identity products, this would be [Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview) ([pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/active-directory-b2c/)), which gives you full customization of the sign-in and sign-up experience, user profile storage, multi-factor authentication, and OpenID Connect/OAuth 2.0 on top of all that.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting - I think this will only partially answer your question but hopefully it helps to provide a direction:

**USER SETUP**

Sounds like you want to add users under your own organisation, such as 'yourcompany.com' and assign users an email based on their own company: 'john.smith@somepartner.com'.

I'm pretty certain that will work fine, since any other Azure accounts with the same email are different user objects:

- When a user logins in at login.yourcompany.com and the email is entered, the account will be matched within your Azure AD domain.

**KEEP YOUR OPTIONS OPEN**

Features and costs of Vendor Authorization Servers are ever changing and all of them have annoyances. I'd recommend an early focus on risks / show stoppers.

One useful mechanism is a simple code sample that focuses on aspects such as login branding, and can be pointed to any standards compliant Authorization Server.

**KEEP YOUR UI AND API CODE PORTABLE**

Integrating OAuth 2.0 into your UIs and APIs effectively involves a learning curve. Keep your UIs and APIs standards based and use the best libraries.

**RESOURCES**

If interested in this approach, some [Visual Posts](https://authguidance.com/home/mainindex/) of mine may be useful, which include:

- An [Azure AD Code Web UI + API Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure) you could use for evaluation
- An [AWS Cloud Solution](https://authguidance.com/2018/11/25/cloud-hosting/) that focuses on hosting of a software platform

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I interpret what you're saying as "in order to use Azure's OAuth2, then yes, the users do need to be in the Azure AD". Can you confirm that? Or is there a cheaper way? At this point I'm mostly focused on the cost, because I'm pretty sure we're not willing to spend more than say $1,500 per month on this. At least _nowhere_ near $600,000 per month. Especially because we have many users, but they don't log in frequently, so performance demands aren't that high.

Comment: Azure AD can federate with external standards based identity providers, such as those that use SAML2P, so users can exist in external sources. However, I suspect this will 'create on first use' a user entry in Azure AD which counts as a user - I've done this with similar providers but not Azure AD. Feels like the Free Tier is what should work but currently there is a stupid limitation of zero branding customization - which will get better over time. At the very least I would raise this with your Microsoft account manager and tell them you are considering going elsewhere (lol) ...

Comment: Thanks. That confirms my suspicion. What is also unacceptable for us about the Free Tier is the lack of SLA guarantees... Our customers don't login in frequently, but when they do, it _must_ work.

Comment: The published [Azure AD SLAs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/active-directory/v1_0/)

Answer (score 0):

If you **just** wanted to host user accounts and sign them to various apps using OpenId and OAuth, the [free edition](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/) *will suffice*.

Now if you start exploring options like 'Company branding (customization of logon & logout pages, access panel)', then yes they cost money.

Comment: This is why I explicitly wrote: "we want "Company branding (customization of logon & logout pages, access panel)" and SLAs"